# Configuring Clojurescript project for garden & hiccup compiled output

Tags: clojure, clojurescript, hiccup

How to configure project.clj file to configure it to output html & css files from hiccup & garden on compiling, so that i can deploy to server without any dynamic css/html loading on client side ?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't really need to use Leiningen, using Boot you can do it easily with [perun.io](https://perun.io), especially if website is the primary objective:

https://perun.io/guides/getting-started/

https://github.com/hashobject/perun.

I rewrote my website that way https://github.com/ArchieT/website-archiet.

If there is a need to use Lein, maybe I'll look at it later as I don't have much time right now.

It should not be hard to do.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. Consider providing an explanation of how perun.io outputs html & css from hiccup & garden. Maybe you could include which project.clj keys are relevant and what they do.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `lein-garden` leiningen plugin: https://github.com/noprompt/lein-garden.

Here's an example config.

```
(defproject cash-money "1.1.1"
  :plugins [[lein-garden "X.X.X"]]
  :garden {:builds [{;; Optional name of the build:
                     :id "screen"
                     ;; Source paths where the stylesheet source code is
                     :source-paths ["src/styles"]
                     ;; The var containing your stylesheet:
                     :stylesheet cash-money.core/screen
                     ;; Compiler flags passed to `garden.core/css`:
                     :compiler {;; Where to save the file:
                                :output-to "resources/screen.css"
                                ;; Compress the output?
                                :pretty-print? false}}]})
```

Then you can run `lein garden auto` to watch for changes and automatically recompile.

If you want an example of a codebase using this: https://github.com/Dexterminator/spotify-data-extrapolator/tree/db8d6e16529940272409598c8ac0fdbbaf739646

To help you find stuff like this in the future, I'll describe a process for discovery.

I found this by going to the `garden` github repository (https://github.com/noprompt/garden) and looking through the code for a bit of text that looked like it would be unique to `garden` so that I could search all of github and find other repositories that used `garden`. The bit of text I chose was `defpseudoelement`. I scanned the projects that were already using `garden` and found one that mentioned running `lein garden auto` in the readme. Searching again for `lein garden auto` took me to the `lein-garden` leiningen plugin. In hindsight, it would probably make more sense to see what other libraries the author of `garden` has written. That would have taken us directly to the plugin. C'est la vie.